# Replace Woocommerce Images

Tags: images

I have a running eCommerce site, but I've recently created new product imagery for the entire site. The new images are named identical to the old images, so would simply dumping them via FTP work? Could my customers still have old cached versions in their browser which don't update to the newer models? I'm trying to avoid having to go through every single product and manually set the new images. I'm open to buying a plugin if there's one that'll help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, trying to pull a fast one on the WordPress media library with FTP won't work. You'll need to import them through the WP admin so they get added to the database, resized, and whatever other special sauce WP adds.

I've never used it, but this plugin sounds like it might be right up your alley.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/

Comment: Sadly this plugin doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ah, bummer. Looks like your best bet is to find a 13 kid who needs to make some extra cash and start linking images.

Comment: My workaround solution was to purchase [Woocommerce Advanced Bulk Edit](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-advanced-bulk-edit/8011417) and just delete, reupload, and reset the images. It's not ideal, but it's better than nothing. :/

Comment: ah, my one last ditch idea that I'll throw out would be to upload via FTP and replace the images (it would have to be the same file path and everything). Then go into the WooCommerce image sizes and change all of them. Even if just by a pixel. THEN run the regenerate thumbnails script. The new images size would trigger the need for regenerating thumbnails, where leaving them the same would not (likely why the above answer didn't create any new images). It's hacky, but it might work...

Answer (score -1):

Well, this can be relative easy if all media library was uploaded via Wordpress, so an update via FTP can be done.

Once you have uploaded all new images (the main of each post), you have to run an update for thumbnails because WP takes the main image and creates thumbnails like: image20, the thumbnail will be image20-200x250 image20-640x380 and so on as your template requires. So via FTP you can update the main, but thumbnails need to be refreshed.

For this you can run a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/ this will create new thumbnails and will and delete the ones you do not need on your template.

Comment: This didn't work. :(

Comment: @rob This works if the image is registered inside a post, page or CPT. I've done these steps inside several woocommerce and still I have to do it when I change some image samples from premium templates to adjust to new image sizes.